# SharePoint 2019 Crawl of XML Files Is Not Indexing All Desired Fields

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search, xml, crawled-property, ifilter

**SharePoint 2019 Search - Crawling of XML Files Is Not Getting/Indexing All Desired Fields**

In the past, when I was working with **Search Server Express 2010**, I used an **xml iFilter** from iFilterShop that allowed fields such as the following "Engine Oil Pressure" to be indexed:

```
<acronym id="106" showdefinition="y" text="Engine Oil Pressure" name="EOP"/>
```

The **iFilter** config file had items such as:

```
<metadata>
    <default>
    </default>
    <exclude>//*</exclude>
    <include>
       <mapping>
         <xpath>//acronym/@text</xpath>
          <property><name>AcronymText</name></property>
       </mapping>
```

**SharePoint 2019** does not crawl such items by default and the above iFilter does not support SP 2019.

**Is there some setting within SharePoint Central Administration that really can be set up to do this, and I am just missing it?**

If not, **do vendors even exist that have such xml iFilters available for SP 2019**? (just wondering if there is such a thing)

I know there are **Search Schema and Managed Properties**, but I believe these are for managing items that have *already been crawled*.